# Solving inequality with absolute values and fraction

Tags: calculus, inequality, absolute-value

I'm new to inequalities and tried to look everywhere looking for an explanation on how to solve such problems with no luck.

Can anyone please explain how to solve:

$(7|a|-1)/(4-|a|)≥3$

Can I use cross multiplication here to get:
$7|a|-1 ≥ 3(4-|a|)$ ??

Edit: I don't know how to format the problem here on stachexchange but I added parenthesises to make it clearer

Comment: @Niroda:  Your post does not look good and I have edited it. We've been here longer than you and surely more experienced than you in post/edit. So let the more experienced users make your post look better.

Comment: You can only do that if you know that $4- |a| > 0$.  If $4-|a| < 0$ then the exact opposite is true $7|a|-1 \le 3(4-|a|)$.

Comment: In your first edit you had $7|a| -\frac 14 - |a| \ge 3$ which would mean $6|a| \ge 3\frac 14$.  Deepsea interpreted it to mean $\frac {7|a| -1}{4-|a|} \ge 3$.   Was that the correct interpretation?

Comment: see @Alberto Saracco answer. He wrote it correctly as the problem I have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't cross-multiply without caution.

**Hint**:

- First, the domain of validity of the inequation is $\mathbf R\smallsetminus\{-4,4\}$.
- Next, ,if $|a|<4$, it is equivalent to 
  $$7|a|-1\ge 12-3|a|\iff |a|\ge\frac{13}{10}.$$
- Last, if $|a|>4$, it is equivalent to
  $$|a|-1\le 12-3|a|\iff |a|\le\frac{13}{10}.$$

Can you end, taking into account the various conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you wanted to write

$$\frac{7|a|-1}{4-|a|}\geq3$$

Just bring it to the same denominator:

$$\frac{7|a|-1-3(4-|a|)}{4-|a|}\geq0$$

Then evaluate the sign of numerator and denominator. You cannot do what you tried to, because you do not know the sign of $4-|a|$ and multiplying by a negative number reverses the inequality.

Comment: Thank you! that exactly what I wanted to write!

Answer (score 0):

**hint:** Solve for $|a|$ first and if $|a| \le r \implies -r \le a \le r$, and if $|a| \ge r \implies a \le -r \text{ or } a \ge r$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $7\lvert a\rvert-\lvert a\rvert=6\lvert a\rvert$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply both sides by the nonnegative quantity $(4-|a|)^2$ to get $$(7|a|-1)(4-|a|)\ge 3(4-|a|)^2.$$ Expanding and simplifying gives $$53|a|\ge 10a^2+52,$$ and now you may square both sides (which are both nonnegative) to give $$(53a)^2\ge (10a^2+52)^2.$$ Rearranging and factoring then gives $$(53a-10a^2+52)(53a-10a^2-52)\ge 0.$$ From here I believe you can proceed jollily.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cross multiply because you do not know that $4-|a| > 0$.

You can do 2 cases.

$4-|a| > 0$ or $4 > |a|$ then

$7|a|-1 \ge 3(4-|a|)$

$7|a|- 1 \ge 12-4|a|$

$11|a| \ge 13

So $|a| \ge \frac {13}{11}$ and $\frac {13}{11} \le |a| < 4$

so $\frac {13}{11} \le a < 4$ or $-4 < a \le -\frac {13}{11}$.

Case 2:

$4-|a| < 0$ and $4 < |a|$

then $7|a|-1 \le 3(4-|a|)

$7|a|- 1 \le 12-4|a|$

$11|a| \le 13$

$|a| \le \frac {13}{11}$.

But that contradicts $|a| > 4$  so there are no solutions.

....

Or you can bring to the same side of the inequality

$\frac {7|a|-1}{4-|a|} \ge 3$

$\frac {7|a|-1}{4-|a|} - 3 \ge 0$

$\frac {7|a|-1 -3(4-|a|)}{4-|a|} \ge 0$

$\frac {11|a| -13}{4-|a|} \ge 0$.

so either

Case 1:

$11|a| - 13 \ge 0$ and $4-|a| > 0$

and $\frac {13}{11} \le |a| < 4$ so

so $\frac {13}{11} \le a < 4$ or $-4 < a \le -\frac {13}{11}$.

Case 2:

$11|a|-13 \le 0$ and $4-|a| < 0$

And $a\le \frac {13}{11} $ and $|a| > 4$ which is impossible.